# android Boot BroadcastReceiver is not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i have made a background service, that must run after booting the system. so i crested a boot broadcast receiver, but it is not working. my manifest file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mybroadcastreceiver"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver 
        android:name=".MyBroadCastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
       <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
       </action>
       </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mybroadcastreceiver.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

and my receiver class is like this:

```
package com.example.mybroadcastreceiver;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
Toast.makeText(arg0,"Broadcast Received",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();             
    //here i want to start a service,can i start service like this?
    Intent service = new Intent(arg0, My_Service.class);
    arg0.startService(service);
}}
```

Comment: You have not registered your service in your manifest..

Comment: ok , i have registered service as
     <service android:name=".My_Service" >
        </service>
but it is still not working.

Comment: just write package name before name of a class in receiver and in service in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Give package name for receiver in manifest file

```
<receiver 
        android:name="yourpackagename.MyBroadCastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
       <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
       </action>
       </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to register your `My_Service` service in AndroidManifest.xml file, Just register it as follows in side the application tag,

```
<service android:name="com.example.mybroadcastreceiver.My_Service" ></service>
```